# Rails form_for with associations defined and multipart set to true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So I have one form working just fine:

```
<%= form_for([@document, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

And then I have another form where I need to include a Carrierwave upload that is like this:

```
<%= form_for([@document, @comment]), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

The first one works fine but the second one breaks by pointing to the form definition with the error:

```
undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010475dde8>:0x0000010475a440>
```

Any ideas?  Running Rails 3.0.0 with Ruby 1.9.2p180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for([@document, @comment], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Oddly enough, my error had to do with a different attribute that wasn't being filled in but the presence of which was required.  I don't know why it was complaining about the form.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= form_for (@comment, :url => [@document, @comment], :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>`

I believe that will fix it for you.